# spacing between Tables in word document

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

```vb
'    Set wrdTable1 = objDoc.Tables.Add(objDoc.Range, 20, 2)
    Set wrdTable1 = objDoc.Tables.Add(Range:=objWord.Selection.Range, NumRows:=20, NumColumns:=2, _
         DefaulttableBehavior:=wdWord9TableBehavior, AutoFitBehavior:=wdAutoFitFixed)

    wrdTable1.Borders.Enable = False

    With wrdTable1.Rows(1)
        .Cells(1).Range.Text = "Tele: @@@@"
        .Cells(1).Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphLeft
        .Cells(2).Range.Text = "!@@@@@@##@#"
        .Cells(2).Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphLeft
    End With

    wrdTable1.Rows(2).Cells(2).Range.Text = "PIN- 9@@@@@"
    wrdTable1.Rows(3).Cells(2).Range.Text = "##########"
    wrdTable1.Rows(20).Cells.Merge
    wrdTable1.Rows(20).Cells(1).Range.Text = "2.   It is under ref :-"
    wrdTable1.Rows(20).Cells(1).Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphJustify

    wrdTable1.Range.InsertParagraphAfter

    Set wrdTable2 = objDoc.Tables.Add(wrdTable1.Range.Next, ntotalRecords, ntotalColumns) 
    Dim intRow As Integer
    Dim intCol As Integer

    With wrdTable2

        intCtr = 1: intRow = 1
        While (Sheets("SummaryDVBan").Cells(intCtr, 11).FormulaR1C1 <> "")

            For intCol = 1 To ntotalColumns

                .cell(intRow, intCol).Range.InsertAfter Sheets("SummaryDVBan").Cells(intCtr, intCol + 10).FormulaR1C1

            Next intCol

        intCtr = intCtr + 1
        intRow = intRow + 1
        Wend

        .Columns(1).SetWidth 40, wdAdjustFirstColumn
        .Columns(2).SetWidth 120, wdAdjustFirstColumn
        .Columns(3).SetWidth 60, wdAdjustFirstColumn
        .Columns(4).SetWidth 90, wdAdjustFirstColumn
        .Columns(5).SetWidth 65, wdAdjustFirstColumn
        .Columns(6).SetWidth 60, wdAdjustFirstColumn
        .Columns(7).SetWidth 90, wdAdjustFirstColumn

        .Style = "Table Grid"
        .Borders.Enable = True
        .Rows(1).Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
        .Rows(1).Range.Bold = True
        .Rows(1).HeadingFormat = True
        .Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphJustify
        .Borders.InsideLineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle

    End With
    wrdTable2.Range.InsertParagraphAfter

    Set wrdTable3 = objDoc.Tables.Add(wrdTable2.Range.Next, 7, 4) ' insert table 3
    wrdTable3.Borders.Enable = False

    w = wrdTable3.Rows(1).Cells(1).Width * 4
    w1 = w * 0.26

    For X = 1 To 7
       With wrdTable3.Rows(X)
            .Cells(1).Width = w1
            .Cells(2).Width = w1
            .Cells(3).Width = w1
            .Cells(4).Width = w1
            .Height = 16
        End With
    Next X

    wrdTable3.Rows(1).Cells.Merge
    wrdTable3.Rows(1).Cells(1).Range.Text = "3.   The confirmation at the earliest pl."
    wrdTable3.Rows(1).Cells(1).Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphJustify
    wrdTable3.Rows(1).Cells(1).Range.ParagraphFormat.LineSpacingRule = wdLineSpaceAtLeast
    wrdTable3.Rows(1).Cells(1).Range.ParagraphFormat.LineSpacing = 18

    

    With objDoc.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range
        .Text = "REQUEST REMINDER"
        .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
        .Font.Bold = True
        .Font.Name = "Arial"
        .Font.Size = 12
        .Font.Underline = wdUnderlineSingle
        .InsertParagraphAfter
        .ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 12          ' twice the font size for 1 "blank line"
    End With

End Sub
```

the above code adds three tables into the word document however, the output document is showing the first two tables as joint. Also the when the table2 is spilling over the next page the output word document has the first table being repeated again on the second page. the first table is also  being shown with gridlines despite the gridlines set as false.

In the output first and third table is to be without gridlines. first and second table needs to have space between them. the second table is with  gridlines.  and the first table is not required to repeat itself

Comment: Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and consider editing your question. Gridlines as false is a document display setting, not a table-specific setting. Borders are a table-specific setting. A table must have an empty paragraph after the table to keep two tables from merging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the document to insert the paragraph and a section break, and also use the document to reference the range to add the next table

```
    objDoc.Paragraphs.Last.Range.InsertParagraphAfter
    objDoc.Paragraphs.Last.Range.InsertBreak Type:=wdSectionBreakContinuous

    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = objDoc.Range(objDoc.Paragraphs.Last.Range.Start, objDoc.Paragraphs.Last.Range.End)
    Set wrdTable2 = objDoc.Tables.Add(rng, ntotalrecords, ntotalColumns)
    Dim intRow As Integer
    Dim intCol As Integer
```

Comment: how do  i  set the left indent of table wrdTable2. i  have tried all possible combinations with SetLeftIndent LeftIndent, IndentLevel but nothing is helping. pls help

Comment: yes the earlier solution to space out the tables worked ....thanks

Comment: For the indent take a look at this learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.rows.horizontalposition